# Run block of commands parallelly & save output to a file sequentially

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I'm looking for a Linux Shell script where I can Run a block of commands in parallel & save output to a file sequentially.

For example:

```
for each line in file.txt
{
    Execute A
    Execute B
    Execute C > Save output to output.txt
}
```

How do we make sure the `output.txt` has sequential output & the block of commands can be run in parallel.

Comment: Please post bash code here, if you have a question about bash, not some pseudocode.

Comment: Why so cryptic? What are you actually trying to do? Executing 3 processes for each line of large files is rarely a good way to proceed...

Answer (score 4):

The `wait` bash builtin waits for all background jobs. So redirecting their output to a temporary file, waiting until they end, and concatenating the temporary files should be about what you want. Example where we replace `Execute A` by `( echo "A"; sleep 5` )`:

```sh
if tA=$(mktemp); then ( echo "A"; sleep 5 ) > "$tA" & fi
if tB=$(mktemp); then ( echo "B"; sleep 5 ) > "$tB" & fi
if tC=$(mktemp); then ( echo "C"; sleep 5 ) > "$tC" & fi
wait
cat "$tA" "$tB" "$tC" > output.txt
rm -f "$tA" "$tB" "$tC"
```

As noted by Léa Gris, when creating temporary files with `mktemp` it is always better to ensure that they are properly deleted even if the process is terminated before it explicitly deletes them. So the following is cleaner:

```sh
unset tA tB tC
trap 'rm -f -- "$tA" "$tB" "$tC"' EXIT TERM
if tA=$(mktemp); then ( echo "A"; sleep 5 ) > "$tA" & fi
if tB=$(mktemp); then ( echo "B"; sleep 5 ) > "$tB" & fi
if tC=$(mktemp); then ( echo "C"; sleep 5 ) > "$tC" & fi
wait
cat "$tA" "$tB" "$tC" > output.txt
```

Comment: Before creating the temp files, register a cleanup trap: `unset tA tB tC; trap 'rm -f -- "$tA" "$tB" "$tC"' EXIT TERM`

Comment: @LéaGris Good point. I added this.